# Having some problems with the XML layouts (android development)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I've just started learning the android lessons about android development. I was creating a text editor where you enter a message, you set some options and it display your message but i had a problem with the XML file, I set a Button in order to display the message but this button is not displayed. Here is the XML file of my layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_editor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_text_view"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="12dp" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_color_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_button"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/black_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_button"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/red_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/red"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_button"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/green_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/green"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_button"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/display_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/display_message"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_button"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Eclipse doesn't throw any exception that's why I don't understand.
Here is the displayed layout:
[image: The display_button is not displayed...]

Comment: Post your code for the activity.

Comment: As @Razgriz said. I can see however some issue here.
You root LinearLayout has android:orientation="vertical" which means that the button should be located on the far right side, but there isn't any space left for it. Try changing to "horizontal" to see if it fixes anything.

Comment: @Roman Panaget ummm...correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found your problem:

Change from

```
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp" >
```

To:

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp" >
```

The **android:layout_height="match_parent"** was forceing your button be be out of the screen

RESULT:

Before Change:

[image]

After change

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's logic but i didn't see it